# Spring Boot Webflux - Set UTF-8 Encoding

Tags: spring, spring-boot, project-reactor, spring-webflux, reactive-streams

I've been working with `Spring Boot 2.0.0.RC1` and use `spring-boot-starter-webflux` in order to build a REST Controller that returns a flux of text data.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/")
public Flux<String> getData(){
    return Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
        .map(l -> "Some text with umlauts (e.g. ä, ö, ü)...");
}
```

Since the text data contains some umlauts (e.g. ä, ö, ü), I would like to change the Content-Type header of the response from `text/event-stream` to `text/event-stream;charset=UTF-8`. Therefore, I tried wrapping to flux into a `ResponseEntity`. Like this:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/")
public ResponseEntity<Flux<String>> getData(){
    return ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("text/event-stream;charset=UTF-8"))
            .body(Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
                    .map(l -> "Some text with umlauts (e.g. ä, ö, ü)..."));
}
```

Now, making a curl request to the endpoint shows that the Content-Type remains the same:

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< transfer-encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/event-stream
<
data:Some text with umlauts (e.g. ├ñ, ├Â, ├╝)...
```

I suspected the `MediaType.parseMediaType()` method to be the issue, but the media type is parsed correctly (as this screenshot shows):

[image: this]

However, the parameter `charset` seems to be ignored. ***How can I change the encoding to UTF-8 so that the browser interprets the umlaut characters correctly?***

**EDIT:** Setting within the `GetMapping` annotation the `produces` field does not work either.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/", produces = "text/event-stream;charset=UTF-8")
public ResponseEntity<Flux<String>> getData(){
    return ResponseEntity
            .accepted()
            .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("text/event-stream;charset=UTF-8"))
            .body(Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
                    .map(l -> "Some text with umlauts (e.g. ä, ö, ü)..."));
}
```

Comment: try this `@GetMapping(value = "/", produces = "text/event-stream;charset=UTF-8")`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried that before, but it does not help either.

Comment: I get the same behavior with Chrome. I think that the main problem is the missing `charset=UTF-8` part in the `Conent-Type` header of the response. Since that is missing, I guess ANSI encoding is assumed.

Comment: the problem is not in your code, in curl. You need to set Accept header .  Try this `curl -v -H "Accept:text/event-stream;charset=UTF-8" --verbose  http://localhost:8080/`

Comment: Even with the Accept header set, the result is the same:
`> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept:text/event-stream;charset=UTF-8
>
< HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
< transfer-encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/event-stream
<
data:Some text with umlauts (e.g. ├ñ, ├Â, ├╝)...`

Comment: This sounds like a reasonable change to ask - could you create a new issue on jira.spring.io for Spring Framework?

Comment: @BrianClozel Thanks for your input. I've just created a new [issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16516).

Comment: Are there any solutions?
Tickets are closed, but I can not display Russian characters

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Filter and process response before this return to browser

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    
    import javax.servlet.Filter;
    import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
    
    import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
    
    // esse filtro foi criado pra converter para UTF-8 o response do Flux<ServerSentEvent<String>>
// this filter was created to convert all responses to UTF8, including Flux<ServerSentEvent<String>>
    @Component
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public class FluxPreProcessorFilter implements Filter {
    
        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
                throws IOException, ServletException {
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: Luciano, javax.servlet filters do not work with WebFlux